# How to Quickly Find All Struct Definitions Used by a Function in GoLand?

Tags: go, openai-api, goland

I'm working on writing unit tests in Go with the help of ChatGPT. Often, the function I'm testing references other structs, and ChatGPT requires knowledge of these structs to generate accurate test code. Moreover, these structs might reference other structs, creating a chain of dependencies.

Given this, I need a way to quickly identify all struct definitions used by a specific function, including the structs those initial structs might reference. I'm using GoLand as my primary IDE.

While I'm aware of the basic "Find Definition" and "Find Usages" features in GoLand, I'm looking for a more streamlined or automated method to trace and gather all these struct definitions.

Any suggestions or tools that can assist with this in GoLand?

I have no idea about it.With Shortcut key I can jump to the definition of structs one by one.But when the struct has many fields it will be very messy.

Comment: There is an `AI Assistant` plugin for the Goland You can try: [link](https://blog.jetbrains.com/go/2023/06/26/goland-2023-2-eap-6-ai-assistant/)